# Finding Hosts over NAT

Tags: nat

Assume that we have some hosts over NAT, but we don't know how many.
And, the IP layer assigns an identity number to every IP packet(Identity numbers are consecutive positive integers).For the first packet the id number is set randomly, but for the others the id number is incremented by 1.
And Also we know that all packets that hosts create is going to be sent out.

How can we know how many hosts over NAT we have if we are provided with packet sniffing ?

Comment: What do you mean "the IP layer assigns an identity number to every IP packet?"

Comment: a packet from a host has an ID.for example: if we assume we have 3 hosts , host1 uses a random number i, and host2 uses i+1 , and host3 uses i+2 , meaning that any packets that these hosts send has these 3 IDs

Answer (score 0):

Most NAT implementations will reorder the TCP sequence numbers, so you can't tell how many hosts are behind a NAT device just by looking at the IP information.

Comment: a packet from a host has an ID.for example: if we assume we have 3 hosts , host1 uses a random number i, and host2 uses i+1 , and host3 uses i+2 , meaning that any packets that these hosts send has these 3 numbers. how can we find the number of hosts behind the nat?